# Contraction Question

Tags: real-analysis

Is the alpha in the contraction formula necessary:

$|T(x)-T(y)|\leq\alpha|x-y|$ where $0< \alpha<1$
 what is the problem  if written like this:
$|T(x)-T(y)|<|x-y|$ why this expression is not a contraction?

I cannot think of an example.Please help.

Comment: $\alpha$ need to satisfy some conditions, consider the series $T^n(x)-T^n(y)$ for some $x,y$ chosen. If you have $|T^n(x)-T^n(y)|<(1-\frac{1}{n})|T^{n-1}(x)-T^{n-1}(y)|$, then you will see.

Comment: @ Yimin, What should I see? Can you give me a contraexample?

Comment: oops, if you choose some $x,y$ such that at each step, satisfies $|T^n(x)-T^n(y)|<(1-\dfrac{1}{n^2})|T^{n-1}(x)-T^{n-1}(y)|$, then the limit will give you that $ |T^{\infty}(x)-T^{\infty}(y)|<c|x-y|$, $c$ is a const.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $T : [1, \infty) \to [1, \infty)$ be defined by
$$T(x) = x + \frac 1 x$$
Then we have, given $x > y$ (I'll drop the absolute values since everything is positive)
$$T(x) - T(y) = x+\frac 1 x - y - \frac 1 y = (x-y) - \left(\frac 1 y - \frac 1 x\right) < x-y$$

However, we wouldn't get good results by saying that this map is a contraction mapping - for instance, it has no fixed point.

**Edit to add some random rambling:** A function $T : X \to X$ (where $X$ is a complete metric space) that satisfies $d(f(x), f(y)) < d(x, y)$ without a constant $\alpha$ is not called a contraction, but it's called a *strictly metric map*. As the example above shows, a strictly metric map does not necessarily have a fixed point. However, if $X$ is a *compact* space then one can show a strictly metric map has a fixed point. I believe I've seen this answered in the past here on MSE - but I'll leave this unanswered here, as it's a pretty nice exercise.

Comment: How do you attain the number 1 in the range with this function?

Comment: how is this function any different than x-1/x? are they both wrong counterexamples? I just do not see these functions having the same domain and range.

Comment: @Klara, the function I described is indeed not onto. In fact, its image is $[2, \infty)$. Does it matter? :) Regarding $x-\frac 1 x$, in fact this function has $|T(x)-T(y)| > |x-y|$, so it's not a good counterexample.

Comment: My intuition for choosing the function $x+1/x$ is this: I wanted to push all the numbers to the right a little bit, but the farther along the real line I go, the less I push them. This means $T$ will have to be a distance-decreasing function which moves all points away from their original position (thus has no fixed point). Btw, if you really want the image to coincide with the range, then you can take $T(x) = x + \frac 1 x - 1$, and restrict the domain to $(1, \infty)$ to avoid the fixed point at $1$.

Comment: Yes it does matter  for the image to coincide, the contraction has to go from space X->X. IF X is closed and bounded [a,b] then the two conditions I wrote do not have a difference but if not closed and unbounded I think only then you can find counterexamples. The one you found out now I think works better. Do you want to fix your answer?

Comment: A contraction does not have to be onto. Regarding a compact space such as $[a,b]$, as I wrote in the addendum to the answer, it is not a contraction but it does have to have a fixed point.

Comment: For the fixed point theorem you do have to have an onto function, I did not make it clear the context in my question, I apologize.

Comment: Banach's fixed-point theorem does not require an onto function.

Answer (score 1):

$T$ is a contraction if and only if it satisfies the definition of contraction. Your second example doesn't and is hence not a contraction.

More conceptually, the $\alpha$ is necessary to prevent the existence of a sequence of pairs $(x_n,y_n)$ such that
$$
\frac{|T(x_n)-T(y_n)|}{|x_n-y_n|}
$$
gets arbitrarily close to $1$. The definition with the $\alpha$ ensures that this quotient is uniformly bounded away from one.

Comment: @ Eckhard Thank you for your answer. Can you give me a counterexample?

Comment: @Klara: $T:(0,1)\to (0,1/2)$ defined by $T(x)=x^2/2$.

Answer (score 0):

We want to ensure that $|T^n(x)-T^n(y)| \le \alpha^n\,|x-y|$ tends to $0$ as $n\to\infty$.

And this is ensured by $0<\alpha<1$.

Comment: @ Berci thank you for your answer. Do you know of any conterexamples.

Comment: Yoni was faster than me.